# Compute $\lim_\limits{x\to -2^-}\frac{\sin(x+2)}{|4-x^2|}$ without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute, without L'Hopital's rule, the limit $$\lim_{x\to -2^-}\frac{\sin(x+2)}{|4-x^2|}$$

Since $x\to -2^-$ , the denominator can be rewritten as $-4+x^2$, but there isn't much more I've been able to do (I tried using $\sin(x+2)=\sin x\cos2+\sin2\cos x$ without getting much out of it). Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{\sin(x+2)}{\vert{4-x^2\vert}}$$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to -2^-}\frac{\sin(x+2)}{|4-x^2|}=\lim_{x\to -2^-}\frac{\sin(x+2)}{x^2-4}=\lim_{x\to -2^-}\frac{\sin(x+2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}=\lim_{u\to 0^-}\frac{\sin(u)}{u(u-4)}=...$$